# Dropbox starts by itself even though the option to start with system is turned off

Tags: windows-10, boot, windows-8.1, dropbox, autostart

Even though the option to "Start Dropbox on system startup" is unchecked, somehow Dropbox sometimes starts by itself. I have observed many times on Windows 10 and 8.1. I would like the only way for Dropbox to start is if the user manually launches it.

Comment: If you look in Autoruns (SysInternals - MIcrosoft), there are numerous Dropbox entries. You can try disabling all these. Also keep in mind that if you succeed it will take some time to update before your user can access the documents.  Also, you can allow it to start and make the icon hidden. It does not use much resource, so that way would hide if from the user.